# Remove printers from old print server/deploy new ones

Tags: print-server, printing

I have created a new print server, and would like to move our users from old to new. We have a mixed environment of XP and Win7 (64 bit). The old server is Windows Server 2003 SP2 (not R2 & 32 bit) and the new is Windows Server 2008 SP1 (64bit). I have created an alias for the new print server so that in the future, this will not be an issue.

However, I now have to move users from old to new. XP doesn't play nice with the alias nor does W2K3 SP2. Eventually, the few XP users will be get upgraded to Win7 and the 2003 Terminal Server users will go on W2K8, so using the server's proper name is not an issue since it will be short lived. (win7 users work fine with the alias) I have tried scripting this with VBScript and PowerShell to no avail.

Any easier ways then hopping onto each machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Group Policy to help deploy printers to your computers.  Technet has a nice guide on how to do this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755424(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_DeployingPrinters

For your XP clients, you will need to also have pushprinterconnections.exe run via startup/logon script.  This file is part of **pmcmgmt.exe** in the Windows Server 2003 R2 Administration Tools Pack located at:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7331

If your domain functional level is at 2008 or higher, you can use Group Policy Preferences to clear out all the old printer connections and assign default printers as well, based on geographic location.  We do this on our network, so that all printer connections and default selections are automatic.  See:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2009/06/24/gp-preferences-set-a-default-printer.aspx

Comment: Oh, and if your domain functional level is 2008 or higher, Group Policy is changed so that you can publish your printers via GPMC directly (versus going via your print server).  The GP path is **Computer (User) | Policies | Windows Settings | Printer Connections**

Answer (score 0):

Super old, but pushprinterconnections.exe read policies deployed under the GPO object, not servers. They were managed through the Print Management (printmanagement.msc) console. You can find them with this powershell query:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectclass -eq "msPrint-ConnectionPolicy"'
```